# No properties showing in the attribute window android studio?

Tags: android-studio

When i open the attribute window after selecting the object that i want to look at, then no properties of that object show up. Even after clicking on the view all attributes button, nothing changes.

[image]

Comment: What version of android studio you have.

Comment: how do you check it. i have installed it yesterday, so i think that it is recent

Comment: Do you try `Invalidate Cache / Restart`

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: File -> Invalidate Cahce / Restart

Comment: doing it right now

Comment: it worked thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Crammeur in the comment section, this was a caching problem and it was solved by Invalidaing Cache and Restarting.